# LinkedHashMap casts

Tags: java, casting, linkedhashmap

I have the following code

```
    // Gets title, headers and data
    String type = (String) responseMap.get("type");
    String language = (String) responseMap.get("language");
    String template = (String) responseMap.get("template");
    String title = (String) responseMap.get("title");
    List<Map> header = (List<Map>) responseMap.get("headers");
    Object[] rows = ((List<List>) responseMap.get("data")).toArray();

    List list = new ArrayList();
    Bean line = null;
    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> hmap = null;

    int j, i;

    for (j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
        hmap = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) rows[j];
        line = new Bean();

        for (i = 1; i < headers.length; i++) {
            line.choosefield(i, headers, hmap);
        }
        list.add(line);
    }
```

in the hmap = (LinkedHashMap) rows[j]; line eclipse says

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

I don't understand the error because I used this piece of code (with warnings but worked) before in another class.

```
public String generateReport(String[] headers, Object[] data,
        String language, String template, String title, String type)
        throws JRException, SQLException, IOException {

    int j, i;

    for (j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        hmap = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) data[j];
        line = new Bean();

        for (i = 1; i < headers.length; i++) {
            line.choosefield(i, headers, hmap);
        }
        list.add(line);
    }
```

Why can't I cast now?
Using Windows and JDK1.6

Comment: Because `row[j]` for some row is an `ArrayList` and not a `LinkedHashMap`. Also please declare variables local to the loop (`line`, `hmap`) inside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case,  `hmap = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) data[j];`, it worked because `data[j]` contains `LinkedHashMap<String, Object>`. In order to verify you can put some thing other than `LinkedHashMap<String, Object>` in Object[] data in second code snippet. You will probably get the same `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

In the first code snippet, You can do a `instanceOf` check before perform a blind type casting. This will help you avoiding this `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

Comment: data[j] is List<List> @Musib